# OSMF pseudostreaming

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flv, osmf

Good day!

I've recently found new release 1.6 of OSMF (http://www.osmf.org/) and it looks very promising. It seems to be more future proof than my own player code, but I haven't found one thing inside it -- does it supports HTTP Pseudostreaming for FLV and MP4?

Here is a description what HTTP Pseudostreaming is:
http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post this on their boards?

Comment: The only 'their' forum I found is http://forums.adobe.com/ which throws 403 from all my ISPs. Adobe's admins claims that they restrict access from spammers, I should use some anonymous proxy... :( Not very friendly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSMF does not support HTTP Pseudostreaming.

While it should be possible to implement an OSMF plug-in for this - none exists yet.

-Andrian

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple OSMF Pseudostreaming plugin:
https://github.com/mexxik/osmf-pseudostreaming

Try, please.